# r sourcing private repos from github

Tags: r, github, repository, devtools

Hi I was wondering how to source private repos in github that I have been given access to.

Using the `devtools` package, it is easy enough to source open repos by using commands such as:

```
source_url('https://raw.github.com/hadley/stringr/master/R/c.r')
```

but doing the equivalent with the URL for a private repo doesn't seem to work.

P.S. I know I can clone the whole repo, and then get the file that way, but I'm looking for just one specific file in the whole repo to take, and it's a bit inefficient to clone the whole thing, copy the code and the use it as necessary.

Comment: Error: http client error (404) is the error message, even when copying the URL when viewing the file raw page, which has my username and token doesn't work....

Comment: It would be possible with `ROAUth 0.9.2`. You'll need to create an application from your GitHub profile, generate consumer/secret keys and write a wrapper. Here is my [working copy of ROAuth](https://github.com/ropensci/ROAuth). You can see how ROAuth works in [my package](https://github.com/karthikram/rDrop) here. I don't have time to code this (doesn't strike me as widely useful) but you are welcome to do it if this is a recurring need for you.

Comment: Weird..I'm getting errors even from the dropbox package...getting the following error:
`> dropbox_credentials <- dropbox_auth()
Error in if (verify) { : argument is not interpretable as logical` with a traceback that looks like: `2: handshake(dropbox_oa, post = FALSE, verify = paste("Use the Web browser to grant permission to this code", 
       "to access Dropbox on your behalf.\nWhen you see 'Success!', hit enter in R", 
       sep = "\n")) at dropbox_auth.r#48
1: dropbox_auth()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with R, but I usually include private repositories in my projects using the Git protocol over SSH.

GitHub requires you to authenticate in order to download private code. If you use Git over SSH, your machine will authenticate with your SSH key when you pull in your project dependencies. I do this with Ruby projects that make use of private gems, but I'm not sure if R lets you fetch dependencies using Git over SSH.