# OAuth2 GitHub API token

Tags: r, api, oauth, github, token

I have a Client ID and Client Secret after having set up an application in github, I'm not sure what the URL or the callback URL is meant to be for that...which i think is causing me problems

I also have a private repo that I would like the application to access...

The way I would like to access the private repo would be via R, so I have found some packages that might help including `ROAuth` and `oauth`, but I'm not too sure how to go about using these to get the tokens, as they tend to require a bunch of URLs to make the requests from, and I am unsure as to what the URLs are to get these requests for tokens.
Looking at http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/ doesn't seem to be amazingly helpful in terms of my inputs for `oauth` or `Oauth2Authorize` functions for each of the respective packages.

The end goal is to source files from the private repo, since `source_url('private.repo.file.url')` doesn't work

I tried the basic authentication using curl through bash, but wasn't able to find a token.

Any walkthrough examples of how to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. this is a follow up question from [r sourcing private repos from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380491/r-sourcing-private-repos-from-github)

Comment: Is this a follow-up or the same question? Seems like the same question to me...

Comment: well its more related to OAuth, as I can then use it for the dropbox API as well...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an oAuth token at https://github.com/settings/tokens
and get required file via GitHub API using code like below

```
library(RCurl)
library(devtools)
jsonRawFile <- fromJSON(getURL("https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/contents/filename.R",
       httpheader = c(Authorization = "token 38ebb0393fe1757ffde9c45d81adzzzzzzzzz",
                      "User-Agent" = "RCurl"),
       .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)))
source_url(jsonRawFile$download_url)
```

The format of Authorization header should be strictly "token " + your_token_from_account.